# File I/O functionality is normally available in the 'Microsoft.VisualBasic' namespace, but the targeted platform does not support it

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I would like to open my .txt file, but i get this error

Error   1   'Open' is not declared. File I/O functionality is normally available in the 'Microsoft.VisualBasic' namespace, but the targeted platform does not support it.

I'm using vb2010 and I think the code is wrong cuz it's for vb6. How to change it to work in vb2010?

```
Private Sub zapisz_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles zapisz.Click
    Open "C:\Plik.txt" For Append As #1 'zapis
    print #1, "a" & a.Text 
    Print #1, "b" & b.Text
    Print #1, "c" & c.Text
    Print #1, "d" & d.Text
Close #1 
End Sub


Private Sub wczytaj_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles wczytaj.Click
    Dim strText As String, strIndex As String
Open "C:\Plik.txt" For Input As #1
    Do Until EOF(1)
        Input #1, strText
        strIndex = Left(strText, 1)
        strText = Right(strText, Len(strText) - 1)
        Select Case strIndex
            Case "a" : a = strText
            Case "b" : b = strText
            Case "c" : c = strText
            Case "d" : d = strText
        End Select
    Loop
Close #1
End Sub
```

Comment: If you want help with converting the code to .NET, you'll need to show an example.  Although, I'll warn you, people here generally don't take kindly to people asking for others to convert their code for them :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tools in the .NET framework make this sort of thing much cleaner and intuitive than the old VB6 file access statements:

```
Private Sub zapisz_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles zapisz.Click
    Using writer As New StreamWriter("C:\Plik.txt", True)
        writer.WriteLine("a" & a.Text)
        writer.WriteLine("b" & b.Text)
        writer.WriteLine("c" & c.Text)
        writer.WriteLine("d" & d.Text)
    End Using
End Sub

Private Sub wczytaj_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles wczytaj.Click
    For Each line As String In File.ReadAllLines("C:\Plik.txt")
        Dim index As String = line.Substring(0, 1)
        Dim text As String = line.Substring(1)
        Select Case index
            Case "a"
                a = text
            Case "b"
                b = text
            Case "c"
                c = text
            Case "d"
                d = text
        End Select
    Next
End Sub
```